How to specify File Saving Order Between Two Separate GStreamer Pipelines (Audio and Video)
I have two separate GStreamer pipelines: one for audio and one for video. Here's my current pipeline setup:
gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc is-live=1 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=60/1 ! nvvideoconvert ! queue ! nvv4l2h265enc iframeinterval=60 idrinterval=60 ! h265parse ! splitmuxsink location=output/video_%02d.h265 max-size-time=1000000000 audiotestsrc is-live=1 ! queue ! avenc_aac ! aacparse ! sm.audio_0 splitmuxsink name=sm location=output/audio_%02d.aac max-size-time=1000000000

I want to specify file saving order between both pipelines. Currently after running this pipeline, audio files are being saved faster than video ones. How can I add such a functionality that video files are saved BEFORE audio (audio file can be saved only when video was saved).

This is technically one pipeline. Have two process if you want independent pipelines. Better, write yourself an app that does processing with two pipelines.
